# AngularFire Storage - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to upload file in my Firebase Storage and I want to get the percent uploaded and at the end, the download URL.

I've try everything that I can but I have :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is my function :

```
$scope.createCatalog = function(catalog,uid,setColor,setBg){
    console.log(catalog);
    StorageService.put(catalogs,uid,medias,catalog.logo).then(function(success){
      console.log(success);
    })
}
```

This is my code in my service :

```
put : function(name,userID,item,data){
      var itemRef = firebase.storage().ref().child("users").child(userID).child(name).child(item);
      var itemFile = $firebaseStorage(itemRef);
      var uploadTask = itemFile.$put(data);
      uploadTask.$progress(function(snapshot) {
        var percentUploaded = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        return percentUploaded
      });
      uploadTask.$complete(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.downloadURL
      });
}
```

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a promise:

```
put : function(name,userID,item,data){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var itemRef = firebase.storage().ref().child("users").child(userID).child(name).child(item);
      var itemFile = $firebaseStorage(itemRef);
      var uploadTask = itemFile.$put(data);
      uploadTask.$progress(function(snapshot) {
        var percentUploaded = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        deferred.notify(percentUploaded);
      });
      uploadTask.$complete(function(snapshot) {
        deferred.resolve(snapshot.downloadURL);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have the error anymore but it return undefined in console log ...